# Change the meaning of origin in git

Tags: git, gitlab

We just changed the default branch name in our GitLab repository from `qa` to `main`. We left the old branch intact.

Before, `git log origin..` would show me the differences between my current branch and `qa`. It still does that - it shows me the difference between my branch and the last commit to `qa` (not `main`, which is what we want). (This is after a fetch.)

`git show origin/qa` and `git show origin` display the same commit.

`grep qa .git/config` returns nothing.

`git remote -v` just shows the (correct) repository location.

How can we change the meaning of the `origin` reference?

Comment: What is the actual output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `origin git@gitlab.com:companyname/reponame.git (fetch)` (same for push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git remote set-head`.  The name `origin`, treated as a revision, is shorthand for `origin/HEAD`, which you can write out explicitly, and `origin/HEAD` means what you set with `git remote set-head`.  But I recommend not using `origin/HEAD` at all, neither with nor without the shorthand.  Write out the actual name you mean, such as `origin/qa`, every time, so that it is not ambiguous.

Comment: Correct. `git remote set-head origin main` fixed the issue.